# Renaming column with postgreSQL in a migration

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, doctrine, laravel-migrations

I try to rename a column in a migration:

```
\Schema::table('invitations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('service_id', 'project_id');
});
```

Running this result in an error:

> Unknown database type jsonb requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL92Platform may not support it.

My table as a `jsonb` column, I think it's the problem but I don't know why this problem occurs (because `service_id` is not a `jsonb` column).

**How can I rename my column?** (and why does it not work with what I wrote?)

Comment: make sure to add the `doctrine/dbal` to your `composer.json` file and run `composer update`.

Comment: @AfikDeri It's included.

Comment: Just write pure sql alter table query in transaction.
`ALTER TABLE invitations RENAME COLUMN service_id TO project_id;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote similar migration for MySQL, IMHO, no difference with Psql.
The function `renameColumn()` works only with Doctrine\DBAL` and I didn't wanted to add this dependency to our project. So I did it like that

```
DB::transaction( function () {
    DB::raw('ALTER TABLE invitations RENAME COLUMN service_id TO project_id');
});
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the `doctrine/dbal` package and have column names in **camleCase** format, you can try

```
Schema::table('invitations', static function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('"serviceId"', '"projectId"');
});
```